# Which method is more efficient in constructing classes?

Tags: php, class, oop, dependency-injection

For each of a bunch of records from my database I instantiate a class. Inside that class I call another class.

#### Example

```
$records = array(...);
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $a = new A();
    $data = $a->doSomething($record);
}

class A {
    protected $b;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->b = new B();
    }

    public function doSomething($param)
    {
        return $this->b->doSomething($param);
    }
}
```

The above code is the way I'm currently doing it. However I was wondering if the below would be better:

```
$records = array(...);
$b = new B();
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $a = new A($b);
    $data = $a->doSomething($record);
}

class A {
    protected $b;
    public function __construct($b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function doSomething($param)
    {
        return $this->b->doSomething($param);
    }
}
```

What I would like to know, is if this is efficient at all, which of those options is better and if there are any other solutions that are even better.

Comment: I wrote my question like this because my own code is just too much to post here. But the idea in general is the same.

Comment: Furthermore, the two code samples are not equivalent. The former creates a single instance of `B`; the latter creates many `B`s. Without knowing what is really going on, we can't advise you properly. See [ask].

Comment: Note that the 2 code samples behave differently - option 1 creates many instances of B, option 2 creates one instance. Unless `B::doSomething` is stateless, there could be problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: not a PHP dev, but I understand OOP enough to answer this question with...

Option 2 is better.

This is not really a question of efficiency but of a best practice called dependency injection.

With Option 2, `A` declares it needs a `$b` to create itself. This gives you the benefit of being able to swap out the instance of `$b` with whatever you want wherever you instantiate `A`, and it also makes the code more maintainable by making the requirements of each piece of code more clear. This is great because `A` doesn't care if `B` works or not in order for `A` to work. It just treats the injected class.. which may or may not be `B` -  as a black box. It is **loosely-coupled** and only depends on the *interface* of `B`, rather than the implementation.

With Option 1, you instantiate `B` within the class. This works fine... until you want to test your code. Or change `B` at runtime. And then it becomes horribly brittle. Because every single time you want to change `A` you now have to change `B`. This means that `A` is now **tightly-coupled** to `B`, which essentially means that for `A` to work, it also depends on `B` working - this is not very maintainable because your application essentially becomes a house of cards.

TLDR - Go with option 2, always. It's not a matter of efficiency but maintainability.